# PayPal IPN simulator always giving INVALID response in PHP

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am simulating a Sandbox purchase, but I keep getting an INVALID response.

I took the IPN PHP code straight from PayPal here: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples

I have changed the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to 0 since I am not running an SSL test server, but even leaving them on 1 and 2 like the default, does not change anything:

```
<?php
define("DEBUG", 1);
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {   
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

Result in Log file:

```
INVALID
[2015-11-04 02:05 America/Los_Angeles] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Wed+Nov+04+2015+10%3A42%3A20+GMT%2B0100+%28CET%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=AK-1234&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross1=12.34&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=818471070&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A0KpwJ1YTxR%2FfcX8%2BmJdV9DGt4mO
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this method:**

```
private function PPHttpPost( $methodName_, $nvpStr_ ) {

$api_username   = 'yourpaypal@email.com';
$api_password   = 'QWEQWEWQEQWEQEQWE';
$api_signature   = 'WQEQWEQWEQWEWQEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWE.cT';
$api_endpoint    = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
$version     = '124.0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$api_password&USER=$api_username&SIGNATURE=$api_signature&$nvpStr_";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);
$httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$httpResponse) {
    exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
}

// Extract the response details.
$httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

$httpParsedResponseAr = array();

foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
    $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
    if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
      $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
    }

}

if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
  exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $api_endpoint.");

}

return $httpParsedResponseAr;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! Sorry for the late reply! I have tried it, but it does not work, I do not get any response with this method. On mine everything works except that "invalid" part